# UC Orders and Webfrom Submissions in same view

Tags: views, ubercart, webforms

Does anyone know a method to create a view with both 'UC Orders' and 'Webform Submissions'?
I am using 'UC webfrom pane' to collect some extra info on checkout but am really struggling to add this data to a view with order data.

What would be a possible way to do this? Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

check this out... I had the same issue and was able to solve it: http://archive.org/details/DisplayWebformSubmissionDataInViews

Comment: I came across this video but the trouble I am having is creating a view with both 'Webform  Submissions' and 'Ubercart orders' within the same view. I think I might need to do db_query() within views or similar. I am really not sure thought.